# Solve the task. using 1 array

Tags: java, arraylist

I wrote a small program.

**Сondition:** "Given an array of size n. Insert an element with a zero value after each negative element of the array." I solved this task using 2 ArrayList arrays. I'm wondering if it's possible to get a solution using only 1 array?

**Code of the program:**

```
public class Task_108 {
public void Task108(){

    System.out.println("Input size of array: ");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sizeArr = scn.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> ArrIntNum = new ArrayList<>(sizeArr);            // Declare array

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int val;
    // Filling array random elements from -20 to 20
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++){
        val = -20 + rnd.nextInt(41);
        ArrIntNum.add(i, val);
    }
    // Output array on the screen
    System.out.println(ArrIntNum.toString());

    ArrayList<Integer> ArrWithZeroAftNegVal = new ArrayList<>();        // Declare once more array

    // Adding zero after every negative number in array ArrIntNum and write in array ArrWithZeroAftNegVal
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i ++){
        if(ArrIntNum.get(i) < 0) {
            ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.add(ArrIntNum.get(i));
            ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.add(0);
        }
        else
            ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.add(ArrIntNum.get(i));
    }
    // Output edited array on the screen
    System.out.println(ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.toString());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please use lower case for the first letter or all variables. This code is really hard to read. See [java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: Arthur, do you need any further help?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Task_108 {
    public void Task108(){

        System.out.println("Input size of array: ");
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sizeArr = scn.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrIntNum = new ArrayList<Integer>(sizeArr); // Declare array

        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Filling array random elements from -20 to 20
        for(int i = 0; i < arrIntNum.size(); i++)
            arrIntNum.add(-20 + rnd.nextInt(41));

        // Output array on the screen
        System.out.println(arrIntNum);

        // Adding zero after every negative number in array ArrIntNum
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++) {
            if(arrIntNum.get(i) < 0)
                arrIntNum.add(i + 1, 0);
        }

        // Output edited array on the screen
        System.out.println(arrIntNum);
    }
}
```

I also simplified your code for you.

Comment: explain what you did to allow you to only have to use 1 collection instead of two

Comment: You should use `ArrIntNum.size()` instead of `sizeArr` in the loop condition. The size might change during the loop.

Answer (score 0):

A `ListIterator` works quite naturally, allow addition of elements on the same array:

```
ListIterator<Integer> i = ArrIntNum.listIterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    Integer value = i.next();
    if (value < 0) i.add(0);
}
```